# Cmd line bcdedit parse identifier

Tags: parsing, identifier, bcdedit

Hello  I run command  bcdedit /enum all and I get multiple results. So I just need identifier which description has "EFI network". Results seems below. I just need {xxx-aaaa} . how can I get it?

```
Firmware Application (101fffff)
identifier              {xxx-aaaa}
description             EFI Network
 
Firmware Application (101fffff)
identifier              {xxx-bbbb}
description             EFI PXE 0 (X1 P1) for IPv4 (aa-bb-cc)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can only *enum* by the identifier and not by the description

> bcdedit /enum {xxx-aaaa} | findstr "description"

If you don't know the ID but it's the current system, you can use {current}

> bcdedit /enum {current} | findstr "description"

or {default} if you want the *by default* system

> bcdedit /enum {default} | findstr "description"